# Integration with paypal - Express Checkout using c# 2008?

Tags: c#, paypal

Im new in asp.net i have project for providing service (i guess that don't need to shopping cart ?) and user must pay using paypal account or visa card or master card.

there is no shipping details or tax details just the cost of service.

all what what i need please is an good example in asp.net/c# 2008 how to do it or a website 
that figure out the steps in clear way, i tried many site like codeproject.com
and i read many documentation about paypal.
i already created an paypal account

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php , choose "Asp.Net-C# (ASPX)"